# Отменить повторный вызов js-функции

Tags: javascript

Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var pause = 5000;

        function removeFirstNewsTicket()
        {
            addLastNewsTicket();
        }

        function addLastNewsTicket()
        {
            alert('123123');
        }

        setInterval(removeFirstNewsTicket, pause);

    });
```

Вопрос в том, почему алерт 2 раза отрабатывает каждые 5 секунд? Вообще заколебал меня js. Объясните кто-нибудь, пожалуйста. Раз и навсегда хочу с этим разобраться= В награду дам очков сколько попросите.

**UPD1** makregister. Ничего не помогает. Попробывал вынести - всё без толку

**UPD2** Александр, так и сделал. Убрал $(document).ready() - теперь всё как надо.

**UPD3** Был подключен css фреймворк http://www.99lime.com/. После отключения всё заработало как нужно. Он тоже использует jQuery. Вопрос: как сделать чтоб через $(document).ready() скрипт работал как надо и не вызывался по 2 раза при подключенном вышеуказанном css-фреймворке? За решение - награда 500 очков маны)

**UPD4** У меня один скрипт дважды не подключается. Видимо придется попращаться с 99lime, раз такое дело. А вообще обязательно использовать ready()? Чем чреват отказ от его использования?

Comment: [**Один**][1] же.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/bumbay/dHRP7/

Comment: Скрипт один раз подключен? :D

Comment: Всё ровно [**один**][1].


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/bumbay/dHRP7/1/

Comment: ыва ыва ыва sd fsd

Comment: сделайте заглушку:

заведите глобальную переменную, например, firstReady присвойте ей false, а свою ф-циб поменяйте на

        function removeFirstNewsTicket()
        {
            if (firstReady)
              return;
            firstReady = true;
            addLastNewsTicket();
        }

как-то так.

Comment: ещё вариант попробовать как-то так:

        function removeFirstNewsTicket()
        {
            $(document).ready(function(){});
            addLastNewsTicket();
        }
чтобы сбросить эвент, но, боюсь они там накапливаются, поэтому так просто не получится.

Comment: Накапливаются, да. Непонятно, что вот делает эта css-либа... переопределяет что-ли `jquery.document.ready`?

Comment: Лучше тогда проверку/установку флага при `setInterval` сделать:

    if (!window.__already_set__) {
        setInterval(funcname, pause);
        window.__already_set__ = true;
    }

А если эта 99lime такая странная, что дважды дергает `callback` для `document.ready`, лучше проверку флага сделать для всего этого `callback`'а:

    var real_callback = function() {
        setInterval(foo, bar);
        // and other stuff
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.__already_set__ || real_callback();
        window.__already_set__ = true;
    });

Comment: похоже, что переопределяет и в функции переопределения дёргает ещё раз...

Comment: Посмотрел ее код... Ничего не переопределяет, регистрирует стандартным `document.ready`

Comment: а не может быть проблемы в разных версиях jQuery???

библиотека использует 1.6.4 насколько я понимаю...

попробуйте тоже запользовать её: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: Тогда как возможно то, что 2 раза вызывается. Костыли не хочу лепить.

Comment: @Виталий Кустов - не хочу показаться старомодным, но все-же - вы подебажить не пробовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте переименовать `addLastNewsTicket` на `addLastNewsTicket1223113413413`, например, мало ли что может называться также...

В JS с её отсутствием областей видимости может быть что угодно.

**Добавлено из комментария**.

Ошибка просто скорее всего глумая какая-то... и скорее всего не в том фрагменте, что вы прислали. Попробуйте отключить jQuery для начала... Так, например:

```
<html>    
<head>
</head>    
<body>
    <script>
        var pause = 5000;

        function removeFirstNewsTicket() {
            addLastNewsTicket();
        }

        function addLastNewsTicket() {
            alert('123123');
        }

        setInterval(removeFirstNewsTicket, pause);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не знаю что за хрень творится с хэшкодом. Не могу комменты оставлять. Александр, кроме этого кода js-a вообще нет никакого. Только jQuery подключен и всё. exec, там да. 1 раз вызывается. У меня в любом браузере - по 2 раза.


**UPD1** makregister. Ничего не помогает. Попробывал вынести - всё без толку

**UPD2** Александр, так и сделал. Убрал $(document).ready() - теперь всё как надо. Вопрос: почему ему не нравился $(document).ready() ??

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: добавлю сюда, так как к самому вопросу коммент не добавляется(((
если используется 2 версии библиотеки, то, по идее может быть всё что угодно...

порядок выполнения кода и области видимости переменных (которые, кстати одинаково, скорее всего называются в обеих версиях) становится непредстказуемым.

кстати, можете пропробовать просто убрать линковку jQuery из своего файла, она и так притянется через библиотеку.

Comment: кстати, напишите в support 99lime, кому знать, как не им, что там у них происходит.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вынести определение функций до ready

```
 var pause = 5000;

        function removeFirstNewsTicket()
        {
            addLastNewsTicket();
        }

        function addLastNewsTicket()
        {
            alert('123123');
        }

$(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(removeFirstNewsTicket, pause);

    });
```

Ошибки не вижу должно нормально работать, единственное можно сделать проверку, что окно запущено, ведь мы не знаем сколько времени будет юзер думать пока не закроется алерт, а в это время интервал отсчет ведет.

Answer (score 0):

Прям как в анекдоте, где мужик изучил только взлет на самолете, а про посадку еще ничего не знает )) Для остановки этого цикла есть **clearInterval()** Вот и тормозните им в месте, где это требуется.